# When calling the printQueue method I want to print "O" for elements within the respective limits and without printing any "X" values beyond the limit

Tags: java, arrays, function

```
    private void printQueue(String[] cashier1, String[] cashier2, String[] cashier3) {
        int maxQueueSize = Math.max(cashier1.length, Math.max(cashier2.length, cashier3.length));
        int maxLimit1 = 2; // Maximum limit for cashier1
        int maxLimit2 = 3; // Maximum limit for cashier2
        int maxLimit3 = 5; // Maximum limit for cashier3

        for (int i = 0; i < maxQueueSize; i++) {
            String value1 = (i < cashier1.length && i < maxLimit1 && cashier1[i] != null) ? "O " : "X ";
            String value2 = (i < cashier2.length && i < maxLimit2 && cashier2[i] != null) ? "O " : "X ";
            String value3 = (i < cashier3.length && i < maxLimit3 && cashier3[i] != null) ? "O " : "X ";

            System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s%n", value1, value2, value3);
        }
    }
```

When calling the printQueue method I want to print "O" for elements within the respective limits and without printing any "X" values beyond the limit.

Answer (score -1):

Please format your code correctly, and for this you would edit your code to rid the string value of the X assuming I understand the premise of the question

do this:

```
private void printQueue(String[] cashier1, String[] cashier2, String[] cashier3) {
int maxQueueSize = Math.max(cashier1.length, Math.max(cashier2.length, cashier3.length));
int maxLimit1 = 2; // Maximum limit for cashier1
int maxLimit2 = 3; // Maximum limit for cashier2
int maxLimit3 = 5; // Maximum limit for cashier3

for (int i = 0; i < maxQueueSize; i++) {
    String value1 = (i < maxLimit1 && i < cashier1.length && cashier1[i] != null) ? "O " : "";
    String value2 = (i < maxLimit2 && i < cashier2.length && cashier2[i] != null) ? "O " : "";
    String value3 = (i < maxLimit3 && i < cashier3.length && cashier3[i] != null) ? "O " : "";
    
    System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s%n", value1, value2, value3);
  }
}
```

This changes the code in lines 8, 9, and 10 to stop the value of X being assigned to the string